# TypeError: an integer is required in sklearn Lasso model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lasso-regression

I seriously don't know what went wrong in my code. My data X and y look like this.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
X = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

y = [11775,  3132,  8173,  5911]
lambda_val = 1.0023052380778996

lr = Lasso(alpha = lambda_val, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, precompute=False,copy_X=True, max_iter=None, tol=0.0001, warm_start=False, positive=False,random_state=0, selection='cyclic')

lr.fit(X, y)
```

Getting an error message 
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: Surely the error message is more informative than that?

Comment: Take out the `max_iter=None` and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks, chris small and silly mistake :)

Comment: @AKash_KUmar If the problem is solved, please mark the question as 'closed'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `Lasso` model, you need to specify the input argument `max_iter`. This needs to be an integer.

The default values is `max_iter=1000` based on the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html).

Just use this:

```
lambda_val = 1.0023052380778996
max_iter = 10 # or whatever integer you want

lr = Lasso(alpha = lambda_val, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, precompute=False,copy_X=True, max_iter=max_iter, tol=0.0001, warm_start=False, positive=False,random_state=0, selection='cyclic')

lr.fit(X, y)
```